# How to pass "step" to ExponentialDecay in GradientTape

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I tried to use an optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay isntance as the learning_rate to Adm optimizer, but i don't know how to pass "step" to it when train the model in GradientTape.

I use tensorflow-gpu-2.0-alpha0 and python3.6.
And i read the doc https://tensorflow.google.cn/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/optimizers/schedules/ExponentialDecay but with no idea how to tackle it.

```
initial_learning_rate = 0.1
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate,
    decay_steps=100000,
    decay_rate=0.96)

optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = lr_schedule)

for epoch in range(self.Epoch):
    ...
    ...
    with GradientTape as tape:
        pred_label = model(images)
        loss = calc_loss(pred_label, ground_label)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

# I tried this but the result seem not right.
# I want to pass "epoch" as "step" to lr_schedule
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an instance of `tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay()` might not work with `GadientTape`,it is more suitable for Keras's `model.fit()`, what I understand is that you need to reduce or schedule the learning rate after certain number of iterations/steps, so there is a work around for that, you can schedule the learning rate manually by using `get_config()` and `from_config()` methods of optimizer's class.

```
def exponential_decay(optimizer, decay_rate):
    #get the optimizer configuration dictionary
    opt_cfg = optimizer.get_config() 
    """ The opt_cfg dictionary will look like this given that if you set initial learning rate to 0.1.
        {'name': 'Adam', 'learning_rate': 0.1, 'decay': 0.0, 'beta_1': 0.9, 'beta_2': 0.999, 
        'epsilon': 1e-07, 'amsgrad': False}"""

    #change the value of learning rate by multiplying decay rate with learning rate to get new learning rate
    opt_cfg['learning_rate'] = opt_cfg['learning_rate']*decay_rate
    """ the changed opt_cfg dictionary will look like this, if you have initial learning rate of 0.1 and decay rate of 0.96,
        then new opt_cfg will look like this: 
        {'name': 'Adam', 'learning_rate': 0.096, 'decay': 0.0, 'beta_1': 0.9, 'beta_2': 0.999, 
        'epsilon': 1e-07, 'amsgrad': False}"""
    #now just pass this updated optimizer configuartion dictionary to from_config() method and you are done, now
    #your optimzer will use new learning rate
    optimizer = optimizer.from_config(opt_cfg)
    return optimizer

decay_steps=100000
decay_rate=0.96
optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = lr_schedule)
#loop for epoch
for epoch in range(self.Epoch):
    ...
    ...
    #loop to iterate over batches
    for itr, images in enumerate(batch_images):
        if decay_steps%itr==0:
            optimizer = exponential_decay(optimizer, decay_rate)
        with GradientTape as tape:
            pred_label = model(images)
            loss = calc_loss(pred_label, ground_label)
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
```

So what we are doing here is that when the number of iterations/steps reaches our defined limit or decay steps, lets say you want to change the learning rate after every 100K steps we call our method `exponential_deacy()` pass in the instance of our optimizer and decay rate and that method will change the learning rate of our optimizer and return the optimizer instance, with updated learning rate, you can verify using `optimizer.get_config()` method.
For more information please have a look at [get_config()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#get_config) & [from_config()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#from_config).