# Apply learning rate decay in a @tf.function in custom train loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm making an image-to-image (I2I) model that translates images from three domains to another. In the model I experience some plateau in the learning and validation loss. To counter this I want to implement a Learning Decay to reduce the learning rate based on the steps taken.

```
Lr_schedule = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate=LearningRate,
    decay_steps=steps_per_epoch,
    decay_rate=0.96)
generator_optimizer = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LearningRate)


@tensorflow.function
def train_step(input_image, target, step, steps_per_epoch, generator_optimizer):
    with tensorflow.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tensorflow.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
        gen_output = generator(input_image, training=True)


        gen_l1_loss = generator_loss(gen_output, target)

    generator_gradients = gen_tape.gradient(gen_l1_loss, generator.trainable_variables)

    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(generator_gradients, generator.trainable_variables))
    if step % steps_per_epoch == 0:
        with summary_writer.as_default():
            tensorflow.summary.scalar('gen_l1_loss', gen_l1_loss, step=step // steps_per_epoch)

def fit(generator_optimizer, train_ds, test_ds, val_ds, steps_per_epoch, decay_rate, Patience, steps):
    for step, (input1, input2, input3, target) in train_ds.repeat().take(steps).enumerate():
        input_images = tensorflow.concat([input1, input2, input3], axis=-1)
        train_step(input_images, target, step, steps_per_epoch, generator_optimizer)

fit(train_dataset, test_dataset, val_dataset, steps_per_epoch, decay_rate, Patience,
    steps=NumSteps + 1)
```

- Decay rate = 0.96 # Decay rate for exponential decay
- Patience = 10 # The amount of steps taken before early stop Learning
- rate = 1e-3
- steps per epoch = ~350

The individual images are 160x192x160x1 and the input will be a set of 3 images.

I tried changing the learning rate of the optimiser in various ways.

- Implementing `tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)` [how-to-create-variables-inside-tf-function-decorated-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547615/how-to-create-variables-inside-tf-function-decorated-method). Which helps, but only for the first update of the learning rate.
- Implementing `tf.assign`, but have doubts if I implemented this correctly. [how-to-create-variables-inside-tf-function-decorated-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547615/how-to-create-variables-inside-tf-function-decorated-method)
- Implementing the solution stated in [How to pass "step" to ExponentialDecay in GradientTape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56141142/how-to-pass-step-to-exponentialdecay-in-gradienttape)

Comment: Just set `generator_optimizer = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=Lr_schedule)`. Each time the optimizer applies the gradient, the inner `iterations` variable is increased by 1.

Comment: @elbe. Thanks for the suggestion! At first try this didn't work for me. But I will try it again. Maybe my initial learning rate is chose too high for the decay to properly kick in. Cause a premature early stop.

Comment: @elbe, after some testing it works! Thank you for confirming this works.